# How to access object array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an array, which I used push method:

```
            for(var j=0; j<$scope.currentUsers.length; j++){
            $scope.Users.push({user_id:$scope.currentUsers[j].user_id, student_name:$scope.currentUsers[j].student_name, 
                "A":[{"color":"white"}, {count:0}], 
                "E":[{"color":"white"}, {count:0}],
                "J":[{"color":"white"}, {count:0}]
            });

        }
```

I am wondering how i can access to the count in A, E or J?

```
I tried $scope.Users[i].A.count
```

or `I tried $scope.Users[i][A][count]`

They all showd me "NaN" or undefined. Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "A" field is an array. So, the right piece of code is :

```
$scope.Users[i].A[1].count
```

Otherwise, declare each of the fields "A","E","J" as JSON objects with :

```
"A":{"color":"white", count:0}, 
"E":{"color":"white", count:0},
"J":{"color":"white", count:0}
```

and access them with :

```
$scope.Users[i].A.count
```